# AWS - how to find the total size of a lambda function that uses layers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can you find the total size of a lambda function that uses your own layers including shared layers?  There doesn't appear to a single place where you can find the total size of your lambda function that uses all the layers.

Lambda deployment package with all layers unzipped should not be more than 250 MB.

I want to avoid having to download each lambda layer and I can't find if you use a shared aws layer like numpy that aws provides on how to find the size.  Would be nice if in your lambda function it had a total size of all packages used in MB (idea....AWS...please)!

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [get-function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html) call to retrieve `CodeSize` and check to see if there are any layers added to the function. If so, iterate them over to get their code size. The output section of the above doc is not updated. Here's a snippet of the Layers output of the same command:

```
...
 "CodeSize": 284,
 "Layers": [
            {
                "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:layer:PandasNumpyAndOtherGoodies:1",
                "CodeSize": 70877201
            }
        ]
...
```

I am on CLI version: `aws-cli/1.17.9 Python/3.7.3 Windows/10 botocore/1.14.9`

**Shameless plug**: I wrote a python script for Lambda to do this [here](https://github.com/shreyasgaonkar/aws-lambda-code-samples/tree/master/lambda-samples/lambda_code_size_including_layers)

Comment: Very nice and useful script, but the CodeSize refers to *the size of the layer archive in bytes* which can doubles when unarchived. Is there a way to know the uncompressed size? because the uncompressed size is the one taken into account for the size limit.

Comment: Downvoting as this is an incorrect answer. Lambda package size should be calculated when uncompressed.